# Conditionally set the properties of a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-scope

In AngularJS, is it possible to set a directive's properties conditionally, based on e.g. element attributes?

I am building a small framework based on AngularJS. The two use cases that I have, are creating a child scope, and using transclusion (the latter is a bit more complex, but I have it working in both cases - it is just the switch that I care about now).

```
function myDirective () {

  var directiveScope = false;

  var postLink = function (scope, element, attrs) {
    // the attributes seem to only be available within compile and link functions??
    if (attrs.directiveScope) {
      directiveScope = attrs.directiveScope;
    }
  };

  var directive = {
    link: postLink,
    scope: directiveScope
  }

  return directive;
}

angular.module('myModule', [])
  .directive('myDirective', myDirective);
```

The code above does not work, it is only meant to show how I was thinking about it. **it does not need to be an attribute within the directive** - I am ok, if it is controlled by another directive.

Comment: So you are trying to create a directive that gets told whether or not it has an isolated scope?

Comment: I think I am trying to create dynamic directives. It is not just the scope, but all properties. I actually found an article about that through IRC: http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/pawel/2014/07/angularjs-dynamic-directives.html

though I am not yet sure if I will be able to use many different instances of the directive, with different properties.

Comment: I think you need to define your objective more clearly. Directives are registered with Angular and their definition object is used to "define" them statically. So, so you *could* dynamically define them once, but once you do, that's how they will be registered. Or maybe you are trying to create an "uber" directive that emulates the behavior of different directives? Seems like a dubious goal, but in any case, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve from your question

Comment: I want to be able to assign the properties that constitute the directive, by declaring attributes in HTML. I don't want to recompile the directive, but need to have instances of it, which differ in terms of their properties. By properties I mean the keys of the object returned by the directive definition, e.g.: `scope`, `restrict`, `transclude`.

Comment: @wiherek, these properties are used at directive registration-time - not at run-time (I'm misusing the nomenclature here, but hopefully you get my point).  So, changing them at run time wouldn't work. What is your use case - why are you doing this?